# Get enum by char Java

Tags: java, enums

I have this simple `enum` in Java

```
public enum FileType {

    FILE('-'), DIRECTORY('d'), SYMLINK('l'), DEVICE('b');

    private char type;

    FileType(char type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

And I would like to create it a way `FileType type = FileType.valueOf('d');`, is it somehow possible?

Comment: You'll have to overwrite `valueOf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Renamed `type` to `name` to avoid confusion, but you got the idea.

```
public enum FileType 
{
    FILE('-'), DIRECTORY('d'), SYMLINK('l'), DEVICE('b');

    private char name;

    FileType(char name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static FileType getFileTypeForName(final char name)
    {
        for (FileType type : FileType.values())
            if (type.name == name)
                return type;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Also, beware that `valueOf` works like this:

> Returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the specified name.

So you'll use that to do `FileType type = FileType.valueOf("FILE"); // Yields the FILE enum`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 1 line with a Java 8 stream

```
public static FileType fromName(char name){
    return Arrays.stream(FileType.values()).filter(f -> f.name == name).findAny().orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```